# When does reflect.IsValid return false?

Tags: go, reflection

I am curious about `IsValid` function, because during my use of this function, it never returned `false`. So when does it return a negative result?

Answer (score 9):

As the doc [`reflect.IsValid()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsValid) says:

> It returns false if v is the zero Value. [...]
>    Most functions and methods never return an invalid value. If one does, its documentation states the conditions explicitly.

`Value.IsValid()` is supposed to report whether the `reflect.Value` itself is valid, not the value it wraps (if any).

All the examples below print `false`. You can try them on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kowyrDg9Ym).

The simplest example is calling `IsValid()` on the [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value) (which is a `struct`):

```
fmt.Println(reflect.Value{}.IsValid())
```

The 2nd simplest example is when passing `nil` to `reflect.ValueOf()`:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(nil).IsValid())
```

Another example: start with a pointer being `nil`, in this case there is no "pointed" value, a `nil` pointer points to nowhere. Attempting to get the `reflect.Value` of the pointed value using [`Value.Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) results in a zero `reflect.Value` whose `IsValid()` method will return `false`:

```
var i *int
v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
v2 := v.Elem()
fmt.Println(v2.IsValid())
```

Or in one line:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf((*int)(nil)).Elem().IsValid())
```

Same thing if you call [`Value.Indirect()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Indirect) on the above `reflect.Value()`:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.Indirect(v).IsValid())
```

Or attempting to get a non-existing struct field by name using [`Value.FieldByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.FieldByName):

```
s := struct{}{}
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(s).FieldByName("").IsValid())
```

Or attempting to get a non-existing method by name using [`Value.MethodByName()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MethodByName):

```
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(s).MethodByName("").IsValid())
```

Or attempting to get a value from a map by a non-existing key using [`Value.MapIndex()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.MapIndex):

```
m := map[int]int{}
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(m).MapIndex(reflect.ValueOf(3)).IsValid())
```

The list goes on...