# Why is IsValid() returning true for the zero value of an int?

Tags: go, reflection

Consider the following Go program:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(int(0))
    fmt.Printf("IsValid()? %v\n", v.IsValid())
}
```

Given that [the documentation for `Value.IsValid`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsValid) states:

> IsValid reports whether v represents a value. **It returns false if v is the zero Value**.

...and given that the zero value for `int` is `0`, I would expect the program to report that `IsValid()` returned `false`. Unfortunately, this is not the case:

```
IsValid()? true
```

Why is this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39011295/when-does-reflect-isvalid-return-false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Package reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)
>
> ```
> import "reflect"
> ```
>
> [type Value](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value)
>
> Value is the reflection interface to a Go value.
>
> The zero Value represents no value. Its IsValid method returns false,
>   its Kind method returns Invalid, its String method returns "", and all other methods panic.
>
> [func ValueOf](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf)
>
> ```
> func ValueOf(i interface{}) Value
> ```
>
> ValueOf returns a new Value initialized to the concrete value stored
>   in the interface i. ValueOf(nil) returns the zero Value.
>
> [func (Value) IsValid](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsValid)
>
> ```
> func (v Value) IsValid() bool
> ```
>
> IsValid reports whether v represents a value. It returns false if v is
>   the zero Value. If IsValid returns false, all other methods except
>   String panic. Most functions and methods never return an invalid
>   value. If one does, its documentation states the conditions
>   explicitly.

---

`int(0)` is a concrete value. `ValueOf` returns a new `Value` initialized to the concrete value stored in the interface `i`. `ValueOf(nil)` returns the zero `Value`. `IsValid` reports whether `v` represents a concrete value. It returns `false` if `v` is the zero `Value`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("IsValid(nil) %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(nil).IsValid())
    fmt.Printf("IsValid(int(0)) %v\n", reflect.ValueOf(int(0)).IsValid())
}
```

Output:

```
IsValid(nil) false
IsValid(int(0)) true
```

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [The zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> When storage is allocated for a variable, either through a declaration
>   or a call of new, or when a new value is created, either through a
>   composite literal or a call of make, and no explicit initialization is
>   provided, the variable or value is given a default value. Each element
>   of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for its type:
>   false for booleans, 0 for numeric types, "" for strings, and nil for
>   pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps.

---

> [Package reflect](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/)
>
> ```
> import "reflect"
> ```
>
> [func Zero](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Zero)
>
> ```
> func Zero(typ Type) Value
> ```
>
> Zero returns a Value representing the zero value for the specified
>   type. The result is different from the zero value of the Value struct,
>   which represents no value at all. For example, Zero(TypeOf(42))
>   returns a Value with Kind Int and value 0. The returned value is
>   neither addressable nor settable.

---

The Go programming language zero value is not the same as the zero Value in the `reflect` package. Note the difference in the capitalization of the words Value and value. For example, `reflect.Zero` returns a `Value` representing the zero value for the specified type. The result is different from the zero value of the `Value` `struct`, which represents no value at all.